# How to get new Line or CRLF in PHPSpreadSheet from PHP-variable - even quotes do not work

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

i took a look at the documentation and some answers here on stackoverflow but nothing works for me so far. Actually it seems to make a differnece if i have text in the setValue call or if i have a PHP-variable.

This does not work:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $activerowcount)->setValue($paanhangfiles);
```

But that does work (same content as PHP-variable:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B' . $activerowcount)->setValue("Anhang/Datei 1: https://joomla4.land-dinslaken.de/images/pressearchiv/1930-1939/1930/1930-04-20-Hamborner_GenAnz-Vorstand-S-1.webp\nAnhang/Datei 2: https://joomla4.land-dinslaken.de/images/pressearchiv/1930-1939/1930/1930-04-20-Hamborner_GenAnz-Vorstand-S-2.webp\nAnhang/Datei 3: https://joomla4.land-dinslaken.de/images/pressearchiv/1930-1939/1930/1930-04-20-Hamborner_GenAnz-Vorstand-S-3.webp");
```

I also tried to "quote" the string inside the PHP-variable, but also that did not work for me.

Comment: Do you mean something like `->setValue("Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLast line");`? A CRLF is encoded as `"\r\n"` for Windows as for *nix a `"\n"` would be enough.

Comment: Do you assign the newline with double quotes to the variable?

Comment: Instead of `\r\n` or `\n` you could also use `PHP_EOL`. That will pick the correct linebreak for your system

Comment: @Raphael that's partially right, because the spreadsheet could be shared between different OS platforms

Comment: @Pippo ... i just tried single quotes around the whole string so far ... but i tried double quotes now ... quoting the \n ... quoting \r\n ... putting single quotes around the substrings ... nothing works ... but in fact assigning the text not from a variable seems to work ... but why? content of the PHP-variable is same as the given text